# Inflated or not inflated: true zero dilemma in GLMM

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, biostatistics, glmmtmb

I have the models with overdispersion and almost 40% of the data set are true zeros with biological meaning. I'd like to study the temperature (`temp`) and time storage in days (`storage`) influence on the insect's development (`development`), but the storage is temporally correlated. This is a classic zero dilemma case, inflated or not inflated models?
I try to do:

```
#Packages
library(lme4)
library(glmmTMB)
library(tidyverse)
library(bbmle) 
library(broom)

#Open my dataset
myds<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/ds.desenvol.csv")
str(myds)
# 'data.frame': 400 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ temp       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ storage    : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
#  $ rep        : chr  "r1" "r2" "r3" "r4" ...
#  $ development: int  0 23 22 27 24 25 24 22 0 22 ...

# Zero proportion - All true zeros with biological meaning 
p.0 <- myds[myds$development==0,]
(length(p.0[,1])/length(myds[,1]))*100
# [1] 39.25 % of the data set are zeros

# Models creation Negative binomial

# 1 - Model not inflated 
m_1 <- glmmTMB(development ~ temp + storage + (1 | storage), data = myds, 
            family = nbinom2, zi = ~ 0)

# 3 - Model inflated 
m_2 <- glmmTMB(development ~ temp + storage + (1 | storage), data = myds, 
            family = nbinom2, zi = ~ 1)

# Put it all the models together:
modList <- tibble::lst(m_1,m_2)
bbmle::AICtab(modList)
#     dAIC df
# m_2   0  6 
# m_1 929  5 
#
```

But, is difficult for me, the adoption of highly complex models with just AIC metric as support. Please, any help other support decision criteria for model selection in this case?

Comment: It would be safer to compare `glmmTMB` models fitted with and without zero-inflation rather than comparing one model fitted with `glmer.nb` and another with `glmmTMB` ...

Comment: Thank Ben and now I have just only `glmmTMB`models.  Do you believe that in this case (zero-inflated or not), the AIC criteria is a safety compass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a bunch going on here.

First let's look at the data:

```r
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
(ggplot(myds)
  + aes(temp, development, colour = factor(storage))
  + stat_sum(position = position_jitter(width = 0.5),
             alpha = 0.8)
  + scale_color_viridis_d()
)
```

[image: data plot]

Just from looking at the picture, it's pretty obvious that a zero-inflated model is necessary (there's no way a non-zero-inflated Poisson or negative binomial can produce a bimodal distribution with many values at zero and many values far from zero).

Fit first model:

```r
m_1 <- glmmTMB(development ~ temp + storage + (1 | storage), data = myds,
               family = nbinom2)
```

Simulate the model many times to look at the expected distribution of proportion zero values:

```r
set.seed(101)
system.time(
    pp <- replicate(10000, mean(simulate(m_1)[[1]] == 0))
)
par(las=1, bty = "l")
plot(prop.table(table(pp)), xlim = c(0.18, 0.40))
abline(v = p.0, col = 2)
```

[image: table of proportions equal to zero]

(10,000 samples is overkill here.)
Again, obvious that there are way too many zero values in the response to be explained by the best-fitting NB model (p < 0.0001, since the observed proportion [0.39, red line] is well above the maximum proportion in 10,000 replicates (0.35).

Let's dig in farther.

When I fit a model with zero-inflation I get model convergence warnings (this will vary across platforms), and a huge value of `sigma(m_2)`:

```r
m_2 <- update(m_1, ziformula = ~ 1)
## Warning messages:
## 1: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
##  2: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; false convergence (8). See vignette('troubleshooting')
sigma(m_2)
## [1] 262965681398
```

This means that a negative binomial model isn't appropriate, and we should revert to a Poisson response

```r
m_3 <- update(m_1, ziformula = ~ 1, family = poisson)
```

We can see that the estimated random effect is very small (effectively zero):

```r
VarCorr(m_3)

Conditional model:
 Groups  Name        Std.Dev.  
 storage (Intercept) 8.9098e-06
```

This means that the Poisson variation is enough to explain any deviations around a linear effect of `storage`, we don't need the random effect (although it doesn't really hurt to keep it in).

```r
m_4 <- update(m_1, ziformula = ~ 1, family = poisson,
              . ~ . - (1|storage))
```

However, checking residuals with `DHARMa`, we do still have a bit of a problem:

```r
library(DHARMa)
plot(s4 <- simulateResiduals(m_4))
```

[image: DHARMa plot 1]

It's often easiest to understand what's going on by plotting residuals vs individual factors:

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plotResiduals(s4, myds$storage, rank = FALSE)
plotResiduals(s4 myds$temp, rank  = FALSE)
```

[image: DHARMA plot 2]

This shows fairly severe heteroscedasticity: the storage == 5 and temp == 25 conditions are much less variable than the other categories (storage == 10 is somewhat less variable).

Unfortunately, it's hard to incorporate heteroscedasticity in a Poisson model (because the variance is completely determined once we know the mean). I tried a negative binomial model without the random effect and with heteroscedasticity by storage and temp (which didn't work very well), then tried a hurdle (zero-inflated) log-link Gamma with heteroscedasticity, which so far is the best of the bunch:

```r
m_5 <- update(m_2,
              . ~ . - (1|storage),
              dispformula = ~storage + temp)
m_6 <- update(m_2,
              family = ziGamma(link = "log"),
              . ~ . - (1|storage),
              dispformula = ~storage + temp)

# Put all the models together:
modList <- list(nb2=m_1,
                nb2_zi=m_2,
                pois_zi=m_3,
                pois_zi_noRE = m_4,
                nb2_zi_het = m_5,
                gamma_zi_het = m_6)

bbmle::AICtab(modList)
```

```
             dAIC   df
gamma_zi_het    0.0 7 
pois_zi_noRE  197.3 4 
pois_zi       199.3 5 
nb2          1130.3 5 
nb2_zi           NA 6 
nb2_zi_het       NA 7
```

The `DHARMa` output still doesn't look great, but it's a lot better than when we started ...

Comment: Very expressive explanations, this is not an answer but a class!!! Thanks very much, @Ben Bolker!!!